# ¿Qué tipo de tipo de oración subordinada es "Salió sin que nadie se diera cuenta"?

Tags: sintaxis, subordinadas

> Salió **sin que nadie se diera cuenta**

¿Qué tipo de oración subordinada es la señalada en negrita? (quiero decir en general las que van introducidas por la conjunción *sin que*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Son oraciones subordinadas en función de complemento circunstancial. En concreto, precedidas por sin representan un complemento circunstancial de modo. Una estrategia que suele funcionar es sustituir la oración completa por un adverbio terminado en -mente.

Salió **sin que nadie se diera cuenta.** -> Salió **clandestinamente.**

http://www.gramaticas.net/2013/08/ejemplos-sustantiva-de-c-circunstancial.html

http://www.gramaticas.net/2011/10/oracion-subordinada-circunstancial.html